# qemu-nbd connected device is very slow

Tags: linux, qemu

I used following command to create the qcow2:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 test2019.qcow2 10G
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 test2019.qcow2
```

Then I created an ext4 on device /dev/nbd1. The formatting process is supper slow. And after that I used the dd to test the writing speed:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile2 oflag=dsync bs=500MB count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
500000000 bytes (500 MB, 477 MiB) copied, 656.736 s, 761 kB/s

real    10m56.755s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.424s
```

This is too slow to be useful. Any idea what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is because we have not give the high performance parameters to qcow2, following parameters make it 1000x faster:

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 test.qcow2 --cache=unsafe --discard=unmap
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for later comers:

If you created the .qcow2 disk image with `-o cluster_size=512` option, the speed would also be painfully slow (~ 3MB/s). Testings show that creating the image file without that option or with `-o cluster_size=4096` restores high speed (> 100MB/s).